# can't use egg-mysql in egg.js framework

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm

in my nodejs program,i use egg.js framework to create an API server.I am using egg-mysql to crud my database,here are error code i don't understand.And there is no mysql in the declaration of ctx.app

nodejs version: 12.16.1,
npm version: 6.14.3

> {"code":"ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE","message":"The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received undefined","stack":"TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The \"string\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received undefined\n    at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:713:11)\n    at respond (/root/workspace/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:261:25)\n    at handleResponse (/root/workspace/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:164:34)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)","name":"TypeError","status":500}

this is my config files

```
//config/plugin.js
'use strict';

/** @type Egg.EggPlugin */
exports.mysql = {
    enable: true,
    package: 'egg-mysql',
};

//config/config.default.js
module.exports = appInfo => {
  const config = exports = {}

  config.mysql = {
    client: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '3306',
      user: 'aichechaoshi',
      password: 'Aiche123',
      database: 'aichechaoshi_db',
    },
    app: true,
    agent: false,
  };

  // use for cookie sign key, should change to your own and keep security
  config.keys = appInfo.name + '_1585128324727_7762';

  // add your middleware config here
  config.middleware = [];

  // add your user config here
  const userConfig = {
    // myAppName: 'egg',
  };

  return {
    ...config,
    ...userConfig,
  };
};
```

in service file

```
//app/service/mysql.js
async read() {
    const { ctx } = this;
    const result = await ctx.app.mysql.select('2019_09_zhouqi_brand');
    return result;
  }
```

need help!!!